# Terminating a string

Tags: string, oracle

I need to create  the following string;

```
 'A-NUPHAT','AMIRA','AMNAD','ANAT','ANUCHAT',
```

but without the last comma :

This is my query:

```
select listagg(  ''''  ||   empName||'''' ||    ','   ) within group (order by empName)
  from   ( select  distinct   T4.Rep_Emp_Name   as   empName
  from YAN_TASKS  t0
  inner join   YAN_PLATES      t1
  on     t0.firm_code = T1.Firm_Code
  and T0.Plate_Code=  T1.Plate_Code
  inner join  Rep_Emp_Names  t2
  on T1.Firm_Code = T2.Firm_Code
  and T1.Rep_Emp_Code=t2.REP_EMP_CODE
  inner join YAN_EMP_TASKS_PLAN   t3
  on t0.firm_code=t3.firm_code
  and T0.Task_Doc_Nbr = T3.Task_Doc_Nbr
  inner join Rep_Emp_Names t4
  on t4.firm_code = t3.firm_code
  and t4.Rep_Emp_Code=t3.Rep_Emp_Code)   )
```

How to rewrite the query without getting the last comma?

Comment: This is not T-SQL (the SQL dialect used in SQL Server). The `sql-server` tag is not correct for this question. Please [edit] your question and tag with the proper SQL dialect.

Comment: This looks like Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is you're concatenating a comma to your string of values. You should specify the comma as the delimiter argument instead : `listagg()` is clever enough to know we don't need a trailing comma:

```
 listagg(''''||empName||'''' , ',') 
         ^                     ^
         aggregation arg       delimiter arg
```

The default delimiter is `null`, so if we don't specify an argument Oracle just runseverythingtogetherintoasinglestring :).